# Error Loading objects from a Web Server

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, arkit

I use this code to get my objects on web like the Ikea app, but it's not working and gives me the error below.

```
func loadModel() {
    let virtualObjectURL: URL!
    virtualObjectURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/\(modelName).\(fileExtension)")

    let virtualObjectScene = try! SCNScene(url: virtualObjectURL)

    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()

    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        child.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        child.movabilityHint = .movable
        wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
    }

    self.addChildNode(wrapperNode)

    modelLoaded = true
}
```

It looks like an SSL certificate error, but I tried `AllowArbitaryLoads` and it didn't work.

Must I use `MySQL` or something? I feel like if I don't have any SSL certificate errors, it gives me another error.

> ```
> 2017-11-15 18:18:05.669124+0300 ARKitProject[2908:2157180] Strict Trust Evaluation yielded status(-9802) for [1:0x1c416f780]
> 2017-11-15 18:18:05.669206+0300 ARKitProject[2908:2157180] TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x1c416f780]: 3:0
> 2017-11-15 18:18:05.669430+0300 ARKitProject[2908:2157180] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
> 2017-11-15 18:18:05.669469+0300 ARKitProject[2908:2157180] Task <DF717E27-6EC4-4800-8B1A-01D6B796CFE7>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
> 2017-11-15 18:18:05.670112+0300 ARKitProject[2908:2157268] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200
> ```